# Can I pass JSON to this REST API call? Apache Ignite

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, microservices, ignite

We are trying to put data in Apahe Ignite Cache using this REST API provided by Ignite. https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api.

I want to know if I can pass JSON data to it from spring boot application. Tried the basic GET and PUT it's working fine. But how to pass lots of Data from the JSON.?

Like Example JSON

```
{
Name : CYZ,
Id:12345
Dept: xyz
}
```

P.S The JSON is for understanding purposes only. I will tweak the answer as per my requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ConnectorMessageInterceptor](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ConnectorMessageInterceptor.html) to convert the JSON representation into a Java object.

You can specify it in Ignite configuration as [ConnectorConfiguration#messageInterceptor](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ConnectorConfiguration.html#setMessageInterceptor-org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorMessageInterceptor-) property. ConnectorConfiguration can be specified as [IgniteConfiguration#connectorConfiguration](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setConnectorConfiguration-org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration-) property.

Comment: Let's say we don't want to play with Ignite Configuration. It's already set up and running. if we convert the JSON into Java objects, How to send it in the rest calls? Any examples you could provide ? Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you want to use REST, then described Ignite configuration is needed. If you want to insert Java objects, then you need to use [native API](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jcache) or [JDBC driver](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver).